# not able to interact with webelement when i run the selenium test case on jenkins

Tags: google-chrome, jenkins

my login test is getting failed in jenkins and running correctly on eclipse and command .i think the jenkins is not able to interact with username, password field and submit. i have tried some solution by allowing jenkin to interact with the desktop. i have also tried to run the jenkins using java -jar jenkins.war on command line  but i dont know the complete procedure.

please  suggest with complete solutions

console output:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.45.615291 (ec3682e3c9061c10f26ea9e5cdcf3c53f3f74387) on port 21901
Only local connections are allowed.
Mar 02, 2019 12:17:13 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS

Welcome back!

test run cmd
D:\test-output\testfiule 2019_03_02__12_17_25.png

failed

===============================================
Suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================

C:\Users\designs\eclipse-workspace\seffcon11>cmd /k 
C:\Users\designs\eclipse-workspace\seffcon11>Finished: SUCCESS
```